# Subclassing method with ellipsis array argument?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to subclass an object that has the ellipsis syntax in the init header. i.e.

```
-(void) initObjectWith:(NSString*)argument arguments:(NSString*)someArgument,...;
```

I'm unsure how to pass along the arguments array in this case. I suspect it would be something like:

```
- (void) initObjectWithCustomInitializer:(NSString*)argument additionalArgument:(NSString*)additionalArgument argument:(NSString*) someArgument,... {
  self = [super initObjectWith:argument arguments:someArgument,...];
  if (self) {
     //custom init code here
  }
  return self
}
```

This compiles but the nil-terminated 'arguments' array is only getting the first argument. How do I pass along the objects of a nil-terminated array?

Comment: The `...` doesn't represent an array, it represents a variadic argument list.  Unfortunately, unless the superclass has a version of the method that takes a `va_list` directly in addition to the variadic version, I think you're out of luck.  Maybe there's a trick I don't know about? I'm definitely interested to see how this one turns out for you.

Comment: [This link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html) seems to indicate that the superclass *should* provide `va_list`-accepting version of any variadic method.  Does yours?

Comment: Nope, the class I'm trying to subclass is a UIKit class that isn't really meant to be subclassed, as far as I can tell :/

Comment: could you paste the exact signature of the init method of the class you are trying to subclass?

Comment: @Keller, then maybe you're stuck.  Can you give more specifics?

Comment: I'm trying to subclass UIActionSheet which has the initializer: - (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title delegate:(id<UIActionSheetDelegate>)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...; No va_list initializer in the docs...

Answer (score 9):

The superclass that declares that variadic initializer *should* also declare a non-variadic one that takes a `va_list` (analogous to how `printf` has `vprintf`, for example).  Assuming that case, where the superclass has both:

```
-(void)init:(id)a arguments:(id)b, ...;
```

and

```
-(void)init:(id)a arguments:(id)b variadicArgs:(va_list)args;
```

You would do something like:

```
- (void)myInit:(id)a newArg:(id)c arguments:(id)b, ...
{
    va_list v;
    va_start(v, b);

    self = [super init:a arguments:b variadicArgs:v];
    if (self) {
        //custom init code here
    }

    va_end(v);
    return self;
}
```

Of course, you should be sure to have a non-variadic version of your new initializer, too!

Comment: This is useful, but unfortunately not the answer in the case of a class that doesn't provide a va_list version of the initializer. Thanks though.

Comment: @Keller, yeah, I think you might be out of luck then.  There's no portable way to accept and then forward along variadic arguments as far as I know.  I guess you could write an assembly routine to set things up properly and pass them along?

Answer (score 7):

Due to the way varargs are actually implemented, and the limitations of C language, it isn't possible to pass `...` args down the callchain without a `va_list`-taking function to call unless you:

1. Use assembly language appropriate to every platform on which your code may run
2. Know intimate details of how the compiler implements `va_list` et al., or
3. Try to write a function that somehow computes every possible combination of argument types and passes them along manually.

Of these options, (3) is obviously impractical in any realistic case, and (2) is subject to change without notice at any time. That leaves us with (1), assembly language for each platform on which your code runs.

Internally, varargs are implemented in an ABI-specific manner for each architecture. Conceptually, `...` says "I'm going to pass all the arguments I want as if I were calling a function that took those arguments, and it's up to you to figure out where to pick up each argument from." Let's take the example of an architecture that passes all its arguments on the stack, such as `i386` on OS X and the iOS Simulator.

Given the following function prototype and call:

```c
void f(const char * const format, ...);
/* ... */
f("lUf", 0L, 1ULL, 1.0);
```

The compiler will generate the following assembly (as written by me; a real compiler will probably produce a somewhat different calling sequence with the same effect):

```
leal L_str, %eax
pushl %eax
movl $0x3f800000, %eax
pushl %eax
movl $0x00000000, %eax
pushl %eax
movl $0x00000001, %eax
pushl %eax
movl $0x00000000, %eax
pushl %eax
call _f
```

The effect of this is to push each parameter onto the stack in reverse order. Here's the secret trick: *The compiler would have done the same thing if `f()` had been declared like this:*

```c
void f(const char * const format, long arg1, unsigned long long arg2, float arg3);
```

This means that if your function can copy the parameter area of the stack and call the vararg-taking function, the args will simply pass through. Problem: There's no generic way to figure out how big this parameter area is! On `i386`, in a function that has a frame pointer that is also called from a function that has a frame pointer, you can cheat and copy `rbp - *rbp` bytes, but that's inefficient and won't work for all cases (especially functions that take `struct` parameters or return `struct`s).

Then you have architectures like `armv6` and `armv7`, where most parameters are passed in registers which must be carefully preserved, `x86_64`, where parameters are passed in registers *and* a `xmm` register count is passed in `%al`, and `ppc`, where stack locations and registers are *both* mapped to parameters!

The only bulletproof way to forward arguments without using a `va_list` is to reimplement the entire architecture ABI logic in your code using assembly for each architecture, the same way the compiler does.

This is also essentially the same problem that `objc_msgSend()` solves.

"So wait!" you now say. "Why can't I just call `objc_msgSend` instead of messing around with assembly this way?!"

Answer: Because you have no way to tell the compiler, "don't mangle anything on the stack and don't wipe out any registers you don't see me using". You would still have to write an assembly routine that forwarded the call to the superclass implementation - *before doing any work whatsoever in your subclass implementation* - and then returned to yours, all while minding the same things `objc_msgSend()` does, such as the need for `_stret` and `_fpret` variants and implementations on at least three architectures (`armv7`, `i386`, `x86_64` - and depending upon your need for backwards and forwards compatibility, also potentially `ppc`, `ppc64`, `armv6`, and `armv7s`).

For plain varargs, the compiler is using its intimate knowledge of your calls and the calling conventions of the target(s) to do this work behind the scenes when it creates a `va_list`. C doesn't give direct access to any of this information. And `objc_msgSend()` is the Objective-C compiler and runtime redoing it all again so you can write method calls without using `va_list` all the time. (Also, on some architectures, it's more efficient to be able to pass parameters to a known calling list than to use varargs conventions).

So, unfortunately, you can't do it without putting hugely more work into the effort than it's likely be worth. Class implementors, let this be a lesson to you - **whenever you provide a method that takes variadic arguments, also provide a version of the same method that accepts a `va_list` in lieu of `...`**. `NSString` is a great example, with `initWithFormat:` and `initWithFormat:arguments:`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer, for anyone curious! Long story short I used the stock 'init' initializer and then passed the arguments via a regular NSArray and used superclass setters.

```
- (id) initWithCustomInitializer:(NSString *)argument arguments:(NSArray*)moreArguments {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.argument = argument;

        for (int i = 0; i < [moreArguments count]; i++) {
            [self addArgument:[moreArguments objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is called like:

```
NSArray *moreArguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"argument0", @"argument1", @"argument2", nil];

CustomObject *myObject = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithCustomInitializer:@"argument" arguments:moreArguments];
```

note: Carl makes some good points below. This solution might not be general and plain init doesn't always do extra initialization that an initWith... method might. This solution worked for me, though.

Comment: But now you don't call the designated initializer for your superclass.  Isn't that bad news?  Edit:  Actually, it's probably easy to just replace that `[super init]` with the original initializer and be in good shape.

Comment: I don't think so, if I'm not mistaken, initWith... style initializers always call init, no?

Comment: Yeah, but `init` might not do extra initialization that you need to have. http://www.djehuti.com/2010/09/21/designated-initializers-in-objective-c/

Comment: It's good that this solution will work for you, but we should be careful to note that it's not general.  That is, if you rely on some superclass behaviour in the initializer that's dependent on the variadic arguments, you'd still be stuck.  That's why there should always be a symmetric method accepting a `va_list` for every variadic method.

Comment: Ah, very good points. In my practical scenario, however (subclassing UIActionSheet), using init and manual setters seems to be the right move because of some button ordering issues. I feel like the correct, general solution is still yet to be discovered. I just posted my solution in case anyone else finds it helpful. Thanks for your help.